# SQL - use one line data to get another one data

Tags: sql

My questions is about the following table:

[image]

I'm trying to select id,parent_id and the parent_id body (where parent_id body, is the body row for a line that id=parent_id in the same table), i.e. if we look at the first line in the picture, than select id=11422, parent_id=211, and parent_id body will be the the body for the line that holds id=211.

I have difficulty to find the correct way to write an SQL command that will do this, is it possible to do this? how?

Comment: You need just a simple join with the same table. Search how to do a join. And if you can't get it. You add here what at least your attempt to solve it.

Comment: Any SQL tutorial should explain how to `JOIN` a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something called a *self join*, which is nothing more than joining a table to itself.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.parent_id, COALESCE(t2.body, '')
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` in case you want each `id` value to appear in the result set even if its `parent_id` has no matching `id` value.  In this case, I used `COALESCE` to display empty string for the body.